# Definition- vector field corresponding to a point

Tags: definition, lie-groups, lie-algebras, vector-fields

Let $G$ be a Lie group, and let $x\in Lie(G)$, what is the definition of the vector field on $G$ corresponding to x?

I'm reading Alexander Kirillov's book and he mentions this object many times, and I can't find any formal definition to the "corresponding to $x$".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that Kirillov defines the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$ as the space of all left-invariant vector fields on $G$ (a standard definition). Even if he doesn't define $\mathfrak g$ this way, it is natural that he proves that there is a natural bijection from $\mathfrak g$ onto that space. Therefore, each element of $\mathfrak g$ *is* a vector field on $G$ or, at least, corresponds to such a vector field.

Comment: So you say that that vactor field is the one that $x$ maps to by this bijection?

Comment: Yes: if you defined $\mathfrak g$ as $T_eG$ and if $X\in\mathfrak g$, then the vector field corresponding to $X$ is the only left-invariant vector field $v$ on $G$ such that $v(e)=X$.

Comment: And why there exists such vector field?

Comment: If $g\in G$ consider the map $L_g\colon G\longrightarrow G$ defined by $L_g(h)=gh$. Then $L_g$ is differentiable and $L_g(e)=g$. Now, if $X\in T_eG$, define $v(g)=L_g'(X)$. Then $v$ is a left-invariant vector vector field and $v(e)=X$.